# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (60000,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(60000, 1)'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on mnist dataset and I am having trouble feeding to second placeholder cause of `y_train` because of one unknown error:

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (60000,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(60000, 1)'

I thought Shape of `ys` (placeholder) should be equal to `y_train` columns but it's not working :(

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = 
    mnist.load_data(r'C:\Users\Ati\Downloads\mnist.npz')


# Reshaping the array to 4-dims so that it can work with the Keras API
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 784)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 784)

# Making sure that the values are float so that we can get decimal 
# points after division
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
# Normalizing the RGB codes by dividing it to the max RGB value.
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

print('y_train shape:', y_train.shape)
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)

class NeuralNetwork:
    def add_layer(inputs, in_size, out_size, activation_function=None):
        Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([in_size, out_size]))
        biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([out_size]) + 0.1)
        Wx_plus_b = tf.matmul(inputs, Weights) + biases
        if activation_function is None:
            outputs = Wx_plus_b
        else:
            outputs = activation_function(Wx_plus_b)
        return outputs


xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784]) #same with x_train=60000*784
ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [60000, 1])

l1 = NeuralNetwork.add_layer(xs, 784, 10, activation_function=None)

prediction = NeuralNetwork.add_layer(l1, 10, 1, activation_function=None)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(ys - prediction),
                      reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={xs:x_train, ys:y_train})
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={xs:x_test, ys:y_test})
    if i % 50==0: #print loss every 50 step
        print("loss after training =",
              sess.run(loss, feed_dict={xs:x_train,ys:y_train}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an axis to your `y_train` and `y_test` when you feed them into your network. You could do this with:

```
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={xs:x_train, ys:y_train[..., None]})
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={xs:x_test, ys:y_test[..., None]})
```

Alternatively, you might be able to redefine your network using an expected `ys` of shape `(60000,)` instead of `(60000, 1)`, but I think there will be more debugging involved there.

Comment: thanks for your help but  i get this error when i use first solution:ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (60000, 1, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(60000, 1)'  ..... second one gives me lots of errors also:(

Comment: Then it looks like you changed something and your inputs are now the right shape to begin with. Are you still getting your original error if you just pass the inputs into your `sess.run()`?

Comment: yeah,i'm getting the previous error still without adding any axis ...i think i'm not putting correct number in this line of code :ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10 ]   Or ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[60000,1 ]) Or ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[60000, ])

Comment: hey ..i solved the problem finally with this code:                                                         X_train = X_train.reshape(60000, 784) ...
X_test  = X_test.reshape(10000, 784)...
nb_classes = 10...
Y_train = utils.to_categorical(Y_train, nb_classes)...
Y_test  = utils.to_categorical(Y_test, nb_classes)...

Answer (score 0):

Even though the number of elements in (60000,) and (60000, 1) are the same, these two variables actually different shapes. It is best practice to make sure that the placeholder and the data to fill it with have the exact same shapes. You can easily do this by `y_train = y_train.reshape((60000, 1))`

Comment: Thanks for your reply ...but when i try this: y_train = y_train.reshape((60000, 1))  , i get this error again ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10000,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(60000, 1)'